# Relief Detail Not Showing In Eevee

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, height-map

I textured my model in Substance Painter and exported the textures to Blender. Material seems working overall but Relief details that i made using alphas in Substance are not visible in Eevee. They are visible when I use Cycles however.
[image: Cycles]

[image: Eevee]

Comment: Can you give pictures of both results?

Comment: Hi, i edited post with images

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by replacing the Displacement node with Bump node and connect it to Normal node input on BSDF. Here is how my node editor looks like now;
[image]